# plotting polynomial regression in same plot as the real data

Tags: csv, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have some snippets of code that read two csvs and plot them using matplotlib.pyplot and perform polynomial regression on the same two csvs. What I want to be able to do is plot both the data and my polynomial regression on the same graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np

datax=np.genfromtxt('Delta R.csv')
datay=np.genfromtxt('Example R.csv')


plt.title ('Test graph ')
plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('y axis ')

plt.plot(datax, datay,'o-')

plt.show()
```

and my second piece of code performs simply polynomial regression

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np

datax=np.genfromtxt('Delta R.csv')
datay=np.genfromtxt('Example R.csv')

z = np.polyfit(datax,datay,5) 

print z
```

Can anybody help me plot the results of this 5th order polynomail regression in the same plot as the original data. Thanks GTPE

**edit**

Code provided by tcaswell works perfectly. My only question is why does the polynomial come out so angular in places. Here is my example image:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get Stackoverflow to allow my image in directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call `plot` again:

```
datax=np.genfromtxt('Delta R.csv')
datay=np.genfromtxt('Example R.csv')

z = np.polyfit(datax,datay,5) 
p = np.poly1d(z)

plt.title ('Test graph ')
plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('y axis ')

plt.plot(datax, datay,'o-')
plt.plot(datax, p(datax), '-')

datax_os = np.linspace(np.min(datax), np.max(datax), 1024)
plt.plot(datax_os, f(datax_os)) # 'smoother' line

plt.show()
```

An alternate method using multiple arguements to `plot` can be seen in the [`np.polyfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)
documentation.

Comment: My only question about the plotted polynomial is why does it appear so angular in places? I was under the assumption that polynomial fitting was smooth. I ill add an image to my question for reference.

Comment: @GTPE The way `plot` works is that it connects your points with straight lines.  If you want a smoother looking curve, plot more points.

Comment: Oh i see so it only plots the regression of the data supplied. The relationship defined by the polynomial equation is still a smooth one :)